# java8 how to dynamically get field from a generic object<T>?

Tags: java-8

There is a fixed steps to do something, so I extracted it as a common method, see below

```
private static <T>void commonMethod(GetListAction getListAction, Function<T, Integer> tObjectFunction) {
    List<T> list = getListAction.action();
    List<Integer> proIdList = list.stream().map(tObjectFunction).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ProEntity> proEntityList = getProEntityListByProIdList(proIdList);
    // do something with proEntityList
    // ...

}
interface GetListAction<T> {
    List<T> action();
}
```

Now in diff situations I call the common method as below

```
commonMethod(()->getFooList(), Foo::getProId);


commonMethod(()->getBarList(), Bar::getProId);
```

but I still want to know if could remove the second parameter in `commonMethod`?

```
private static <T>void commonMethod(GetListAction getListAction)
```

but in this case how to get the proIdList from list

```
List<Integer> proIdList = list.stream().map(???).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think that `List<T> action()` should not be generic, because it's always the same.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get rid of `Function<T, Integer> tObjectFunction` is to make `T` be a subtype of an interface. For example:

```
interface Action {
    Integer getProdId();
}
```

`Foo` and `Bar` will implement this interface and, because they already have `getProdId()` methods, this should be easy.

That will allow you to declare your method as

```
private static <T extends Action> void commonMethod(GetListAction<T> getListAction) {
    List<T> list = getListAction.action();
    List<Integer> proIdList = list.stream()
                 .map(Action::getProdId)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ...
}
```